# Debugging a redirect issue for an ASPX page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

At work dealing with others "spaghetti code". Yummy.....

Whenever I got an a certain ASPX page (I'll refer to it as TARGET.ASPX) it redirects to another ASPX page. I put a break point in the page_load of the TARGET.ASPX and it never even hits that! I know the page refers to javascript/jquery scripts (alot of them). Not sure if one of them is doing the redirect. (For example, if a certain session var is not set it's redirecting maybe, etc....) How can I best troubleshoot this? Is it possible that one of those scripts is doing the redirect? Any tools in Visual Studio 2010 that would help me to trouble shoot this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post come code. Theres not much anyone can do without it.

Comment: How is your code achieving the redirect to TARGET.ASPX?

Comment: @JamesDevlin - Thanks for your comment. Just doing a response.redirect to it. And, it does it even if I manually type in the URL.

Comment: @AdamMerrifield - Thanks for your comment. The break point at the Page_load never even gets hit so posting code won't help. No other page_* subs either (init, etc)

Comment: If the Page_Load event does not get fired, then it means that the redirection happens before that. A few places where this could happen are: Page_Init method, some code in the master page, some code on a class from which your page inherits, an HTTP module or handler (maybe UrlRewrite module?)

Comment: Thanks @StefanoDalpiaz. I looked but was unable to find anything. Any tools in Visual Studio that will help me step thru this from the actual response.redirect forward? Using F11 doesn't seem to reveal anything.